# jQuery clone misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not understanding this cloning process... this is what's happening, there are four pictures, three clicks, first photo is the initial state.

In the third picture there are two boxes, that's fine, but rather than each box having one project name input and add task button, there are two in the first box, and normal in the second box. Click the button again and it becomes 3:2:1, next click it would be 4:3:2:1, etc... I don't want that. I just want boxes to be added with one piece per box.

code

```
function addProject() {
      $(project).clone().appendTo(".projectPanel");
      $(projectNameInput).clone().appendTo(".project");
      $(addTaskButton).clone().appendTo(".project");
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: your cloning is working fine your problem is appendTo. the jquery appendTo('class selector') appends the jquery object to every every in the set of matched elements so it adds it to anything with the class name "project"  or "projectPanel" to fix it you will want to use the return value of $(project).clone(); and use that rather than the class selectors in your appendTo

Comment: Could you recreate this in a fiddle?

Comment: thanks to you guys Binvention, Nick Zuber, I ended up restructuring my code, I'm not even using clone at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your appendTo it appends the element to all elements in the set of matched elements so everything with the class "project". for more information on it try looking at the [jquery appendTo documentation](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/). to fix it try something like this

```
function addProject() {
      var newProject=$(project).clone();
      newProject.appendTo(".projectPanel");
      $(projectNameInput).clone().appendTo(newProject);
      $(addTaskButton).clone().appendTo(newProject);
 }
```

using the return value of `$(project).clone()` allows you to grab only the new project rather than all of the projects that currently exist